# Text recognition in a class and patch choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a code that recognizes a text in a class and choose the correct button to click. Now I'm trying to use the number of characters in the class, but it did not work. Some tips?

```
window.onload=function(){  setInterval(autoPickOther, 2500); };

function autoPickOther(){

if(document.getElementsByClassName("text class").length<66){
document.getElementsByClassName("pickother")[0].click();
}
else{setInterval(autoClick,1200);}
}

function autoClick(){
if(document.getElementsByClassName("class 1").length>0){
document.getElementsByClassName("go")[0].click();
}
}
```

Comment: I'll be helpful if you post your entire code.

Comment: getElementsByClassName("text class") -> you can't do this. Also if using JQuery, use $('.text') or whatever your singular-word-named-class is called. You could change the classname to "text-class"? To bind a click in JQuery use $(selector).on('click', function() { ... code ... });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I've made it! Probably not the best solution but I use the text length to filter the right answer like I've thought before. The problem was that I was not extracting the text from the class so following the example the new code would be something like this:

```
var readclass = document.getElementsByClassName("luck");
for (var i = 0; i < readclass.length; i++) {
var text = readclass[i].innerText;
}

var textlength = text.length;

window.onload=function(){

setInterval(autoPickOther, 1000); };

function autoPickOther(){
if(textlength < 20){   //Change number according to the number of characters in the sentence that you want to test
document.getElementsByClassName("pickother")[0].click();
}
else{setInterval(autoThanks,1000);}
}
```